# Date difference in years using C#

Tags: c#, date, datediff

How can I calculate date difference between two dates in years?

For example: `(Datetime.Now.Today() - 11/03/2007)` in years.

Comment: The code you've marked as the answer is actual fact incorrect.  It can return incorrect results

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I have written an implementation that properly works with dates exactly one year apart.

However, it does not gracefully handle negative timespans, unlike the other algorithm. It also doesn't use its own date arithmetic, instead relying upon the standard library for that.

So without further ado, here is the code:

```cs
DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

DateTime a = new DateTime(2007, 1, 1);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1);

TimeSpan span = b - a;
// Because we start at year 1 for the Gregorian
// calendar, we must subtract a year here.
int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1;

// 1, where my other algorithm resulted in 0.
Console.WriteLine("Yrs elapsed: " + years);
```

Comment: That handles leap years on average, but it will be off by one for up to 18 hours out of each year.

Comment: Using this method, the difference between 1/1/2007 and 1/1/2008 would be 0 years.  Intuitively, it should be 1 year.

Comment: Good point. I do not know any other effective way of doing this though... possibly add one to the day?

Comment: @benvoigt I realize its been forever since you left that comment - i just wanted you to know that I believe that that bug has been fixed with this update that I have just made.

Comment: @o.nate after searching though the docs for a solution to that problem this evening, I do believe that I have solved that problem. Thank you for pointing it out, it saved me a major headache in my latest project!

Comment: This broke for us today (12/31).  The addition math causes an off-by-one-day problem for when the 12/31 date is compared against 1/1.  We fixed it by first subtracting one day from the span.

Comment: The probability this will give you the correct answer is quite high, However, if you want this to work 100% of the time, this answer is wrong.  Because of leap years. the start date matters!

Answer (score 68):

Use:

```
int Years(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    return (end.Year - start.Year - 1) +
        (((end.Month > start.Month) ||
        ((end.Month == start.Month) && (end.Day >= start.Day))) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: This would say that 2008-Nov-02 is one year after 2007-Nov-03, most people would say it's one day short.

Comment: You are right.  I've updated my code to go strictly off the Year, Month and Day properties.  It gets a little uglier now but works for leap years.

Comment: I know it's an old answer, but just wanted to add that this can be simplified by comparing DayOfYear property instead of comparing both Month and Year together.

Comment: @Tarec - my first revision used the `DayOfYear` property... But I changed things due to @BenVoigt's comment.

Answer (score 28):

We had to code a check to establish if the difference between two dates, a start and end date was greater than 2 years.

Thanks to the tips above it was done as follows:

```
 DateTime StartDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2012");
 DateTime EndDate = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2014");
 DateTime TwoYears = StartDate.AddYears(2);

 if EndDate > TwoYears .....
```

Comment: Shorter version: If ( Birthday.AddYears(18) > DateTime.UtcNow.Date ) //under 18

Comment: Instead of doing DateTime TwoYears = StartDate.AddYears(2); if you minus 1 day from that : DateTime TwoYears = StartDate.AddYears(2).AddDays(-1); you will get more accurate answer... I don't know it depends on requirement.

Answer (score 21):

If you need it for knowing someone's age for trivial reasons then Timespan is OK but if you need for calculating superannuation, long term deposits or anything else for financial, scientific or legal purposes then I'm afraid Timespan won't be accurate enough because Timespan assumes that every year has the same number of days, same # of hours and same # of seconds).

In reality the length of some years will vary (for different reasons that are outside the scope of this answer). To get around Timespan's limitation then you can mimic what Excel does which is:

```
    public int GetDifferenceInYears(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
    {
        //Excel documentation says "COMPLETE calendar years in between dates"
        int years = endDate.Year - startDate.Year;

        if (startDate.Month == endDate.Month &&// if the start month and the end month are the same
            endDate.Day < startDate.Day// AND the end day is less than the start day
            || endDate.Month < startDate.Month)// OR if the end month is less than the start month
        {
            years--;
        }

        return years;
    }
```

Comment: I've been using this old code forever, but I just got bitten by a leap year. Client reported a 3 year difference was being displayed as two years - turns out that 29th Feb -> 28th Feb is rounded down and loses a year from what a human would actually expect.

Comment: Wouldn't this work?

    public static int DifferenceInYears(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
    {
        if (date1 > date2)
            return DifferenceInYears(date2, date1);

            int yearDiff = date2.Year - date1.Year;
            var cutoff = date1.AddYears(yearDiff);

            if (date2 < cutoff)
                return yearDiff - 1;
            return yearDiff;
    }


Only thing is this code will give 1 year as a diff for feb 29 in year X  vs feb 28th in year Y. I'm not sure if there are rules on that, couldn't find any with a quick search.

Answer (score 13):

```
var totalYears = 
    (DateTime.Today - new DateTime(2007, 03, 11)).TotalDays
    / 365.2425;
```

Average days from [Wikipedia/Leap_year](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

Comment: On average correct.  But not always.

Comment: @Mick Could you please explain in what specific case it would become wrong ? Thanks.

Comment: @NamLe the number of days in a year is either 365 days or 366 days if it is a leap year. It is never 365.2425 days.  Therefore this formula is only going to be approximately correct.

Comment: That's not quite true. This "approximation" is actually an exact number of days in a year (that's why we're having leap years - to compensate this quarter of a day) and with a proper rounding, you'll always get a correct number of years.

Answer (score 11):

```
int Age = new DateTime((DateTime.Now - BirthDateTime).Ticks).Year;
```

To calculate the elapsed years (age), the result will be minus one.

```
var timeSpan = DateTime.Now - birthDateTime;
int age = new DateTime(timeSpan.Ticks).Year - 1;
```

Comment: It's actually not correct as it's rounding up.  I'm 40 and that is reporting 41.  I'm not 41 for another 3 weeks.

Comment: Plus it doesn't correctly account for leap years

Answer (score 6):

Here is a neat trick which lets the system deal with leap years automagically.  It gives an accurate answer for all date combinations.

```
DateTime dt1 = new DateTime(1987, 9, 23, 13, 12, 12, 0);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(2007, 6, 15, 16, 25, 46, 0);

DateTime tmp = dt1;
int years = -1;
while (tmp < dt2)
{
    years++;
    tmp = tmp.AddYears(1);
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}", years);
```

Comment: It's a nice idea, but instead of changing tmp date in a loop, you should increment the number of years instead. That will work properly if you expect 4 to be returned for Feb 29 2012 - Feb 29 2016.

Answer (score 5):

It's unclear how you want to handle fractional years, but perhaps like this:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime origin = new DateTime(2007, 11, 3);
int calendar_years = now.Year - origin.Year;
int whole_years = calendar_years - ((now.AddYears(-calendar_years) >= origin)? 0: 1);
int another_method = calendar_years - ((now.Month - origin.Month) * 32 >= origin.Day - now.Day)? 0: 1);
```

Comment: According to this method, 2/28/2009 is 1 year after 2/29/2008, whereas it seems like it should be slightly less than 1 year.  I guess the handling of leap years is always going to be slightly unsatisfying.

Comment: @o. nate: Fixed, maybe (using a trick found on that other question spotted by Doggett).  I think something like Dana's solution may be necessary to fix the leap day case in both directions.

Answer (score 3):

I implemented an extension method to get the number of years between two dates, rounded by whole months.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the total number of years between two dates, rounded to whole months.
    /// Examples: 
    /// 2011-12-14, 2012-12-15 returns 1.
    /// 2011-12-14, 2012-12-14 returns 1.
    /// 2011-12-14, 2012-12-13 returns 0,9167.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="start">
    /// Stardate of time period
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="end">
    /// Enddate of time period
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// Total Years between the two days
    /// </returns>
    public static double DifferenceTotalYears(this DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        // Get difference in total months.
        int months = ((end.Year - start.Year) * 12) + (end.Month - start.Month);

        // substract 1 month if end month is not completed
        if (end.Day < start.Day)
        {
            months--;
        }

        double totalyears = months / 12d;
        return totalyears;
    }
```

Comment: This solution treats every month as 1/12 of a year. It will skew because some months are not sized that way

Comment: Does not always return the correct result

Answer (score 2):

I found this at *[TimeSpan for years, months and days](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/c3912177-bf95-43f7-8a7f-110c6f361fe5)*:

```
DateTime target_dob = THE_DOB;
DateTime true_age = DateTime.MinValue + ((TimeSpan)(DateTime.Now - target_dob )); // Minimum value as 1/1/1
int yr = true_age.Year - 1;
```

Comment: Doesn't work for leap years... Try "5-Oct-2024" from "6-Oct-1973". It reports my age as 51, but I'll only be 50.

Answer (score 2):

```
    public string GetAgeText(DateTime birthDate)
    {
        const double ApproxDaysPerMonth = 30.4375;
        const double ApproxDaysPerYear = 365.25;

        int iDays = (DateTime.Now - birthDate).Days;

        int iYear = (int)(iDays / ApproxDaysPerYear);
        iDays -= (int)(iYear * ApproxDaysPerYear);

        int iMonths = (int)(iDays / ApproxDaysPerMonth);
        iDays -= (int)(iMonths * ApproxDaysPerMonth);

        return string.Format("{0} år, {1} måneder, {2} dage", iYear, iMonths, iDays);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with months and years you need something that knows how many days each month has and which years are leap years.

Enter the [Gregorian Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.gregoriancalendar.aspx) (and other culture-specific [Calendar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.aspx) implementations).

While Calendar doesn't provide methods to directly calculate the difference between two points in time, it does have methods such as

```
DateTime AddWeeks(DateTime time, int weeks)
DateTime AddMonths(DateTime time, int months)
DateTime AddYears(DateTime time, int years)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime musteriDogum = new DateTime(dogumYil, dogumAy, dogumGun);

int additionalDays = ((DateTime.Now.Year - dogumYil) / 4); //Count of the years with 366 days

int extraDays = additionalDays + ((DateTime.Now.Year % 4 == 0 || musteriDogum.Year % 4 == 0) ? 1 : 0); //We add 1 if this year or year inserted has 366 days

int yearsOld = ((DateTime.Now - musteriDogum).Days - extraDays ) / 365; // Now we extract these extra days from total days and we can divide to 365
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
public int getYearDiff(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate){
    int y = Year(endDate) - Year(startDate);
    int startMonth = Month(startDate);
    int endMonth = Month(endDate);
    if (endMonth < startMonth) 
        return y - 1;
    if (endMonth > startMonth) 
        return y;
    return (Day(endDate) < Day(startDate) ? y - 1 : y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the best code to calculate year and month difference:

```
DateTime firstDate = DateTime.Parse("1/31/2019");
DateTime secondDate = DateTime.Parse("2/1/2016");

int totalYears = firstDate.Year - secondDate.Year;
int totalMonths = 0;

if (firstDate.Month > secondDate.Month)
    totalMonths = firstDate.Month - secondDate.Month;
else if (firstDate.Month < secondDate.Month)
{
    totalYears -= 1;
    int monthDifference = secondDate.Month - firstDate.Month;
    totalMonths = 12 - monthDifference;
}

if ((firstDate.Day - secondDate.Day) == 30)
{
    totalMonths += 1;
    if (totalMonths % 12 == 0)
    {
        totalYears += 1;
        totalMonths = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Works perfect:

```
    internal static int GetDifferenceInYears(DateTime startDate)
    {
        int finalResult = 0;

        const int DaysInYear = 365;

        DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now;

        TimeSpan timeSpan = endDate - startDate;

        if (timeSpan.TotalDays > 365)
        {
            finalResult = (int)Math.Round((timeSpan.TotalDays / DaysInYear), MidpointRounding.ToEven);
        }

        return finalResult;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will be helpful for answering the question: **Count of days in given year**,

```
new DateTime(anyDate.Year, 12, 31).DayOfYear //will include leap years too
```

Regarding *[DateTime.DayOfYear Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofyear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)*.

Answer (score -1):

The following is based off Dana's simple code which produces the correct answer in most cases. But it did not take in to account less than a year between dates. So here is the code that I use to produce consistent results:

```
public static int DateDiffYears(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    var yr = endDate.Year - startDate.Year - 1 +
             (endDate.Month >= startDate.Month && endDate.Day >= startDate.Day ? 1 : 0);
    return yr < 0 ? 0 : yr;
}
```

Comment: This also exhibits the leap year behaviour of @davomcdavo's answer

Comment: You can't replace `(end.Month > start.Month) || ((end.Month == start.Month) && (end.Day >= start.Day))` with `endDate.Month >= startDate.Month && endDate.Day >= startDate.Day`