# How to calculate the number of years between 2 dates?

Tags: c#

I would like to compare 2 dates to confirm that the number of years between is `>= 18`. For example, if my 2 dates are `03-12-2011` and `03-12-1983` then this should pass validation, however, if my 2 dates are `03-12-2011` and `03-12-1995` then this should fail validation.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The `DateTime` class has several handy methods, have you tried any?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

hope this is what you are looking for

```
public bool CheckDate(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    return date1.AddYears(-18) < date2;
}
```

Comment: OP is looking for years, not days. He should use AddYears instead

Answer (score 2):

I re-jigged your question title & description to make it a bit more clear. From what I gathered from your original post you are looking for an *Age Verification* function. Here is what I would do:

```
function VerifyAge(DateTime dateOfBirth)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Today; 
    int age = now.Year - dateOfBirth.Year;
    if (now.Month < dateOfBirth.Month || (now.Month == dateOfBirth.Month && now.Day < dateOfBirth.Day)) 
        age--;
    return age >= 18; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `TimeSpan` structure.

```
TimeSpan span= dateSecond - dateFirst;
int days=span.Days;
//or
int years = (int) (span.Days / 365.25);
```

Comment: OP is looking for years, not days

Answer (score 0):

Check the TimeSpan structure:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use Timespan:

```
TimeSpan day = 03-12-2011 - 03-12-1983;
                double year = day.TotalDays / 365.25;

                if (year > 18)
                {

                }
```

Maybe instead of 03-12-2011 you should use DateTime.Now

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method to check if the age is more than 18:

```
    private bool IsMoreThan18(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        int age = to.Year - from.Year;
        if (from > to.AddYears(-age)) age--;
        return age >= 18;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

DateTime a = new DateTime(2008, 1, 1);
DateTime b = new DateTime(2016, 1, 1);

TimeSpan span = b - a;
// because we start at year 1 for the Gregorian 
// calendar, we must subtract a year here.
int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1; 

Console.WriteLine("Years elapsed: " + years);
```

Refrence [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127363/date-difference-in-years-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this....**
Using this you can get the exact no of years between two days. Only you need to do is divide the date difference by 365.25

```
 TimeSpan span = DateTime.Parse(To_Date) - DateTime.Parse(From_Date);
 int years = (int)(span.Days / 365.25);
```

Answer (score -2):

Create two DateTime objects and substract them from eachother. 
The result is a DateTime object aswel:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011, 12, 03);
DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(1983, 12, 03);
DateTime dt3 = dt - dt2;
```

Now you can check `dt3.Year` for the number of years between them

Comment: didn't you mean TimeSpan dt3 ?

Comment: `TimeSpan` has no year property.

Comment: But DateTime subtraction results in TimeSpan result - which of-course has no Year field. Doesn't answer original question.