# How would I output only yyyy only in vb.net? I ultimately want to be able to subtract

Tags: vb.net, date, date-formatting

I want to be able to subtract only 'yyyy' in my script. For example, starting with the year 2014, I want to be able to subtract the current year (right now being 2019, next year being 2020, and so on). With 2019 being the current year, I would like to get 5 as my output.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
        Module Test
        Public Module DateAndTime
          Sub Main()
            Dim startYear As Int = 2014
            Dim currentYear As Date = #2019#
            currentYear As Int = 2019
            mfgYear As Int = currentYear - startYear 
            Console.WriteLine(mfgYear)
          End Sub
        End Module
        End Module
```

I am an extremely new person to vb.net, so I apologize for the poor attempt at the code above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635037/get-date-difference-in-vb-net

Comment: I don't think you tried very hard. If you typed this into a Visual Studio code window you would see red squiggles all over. For starters `Dim startYear As Int` Do you have a class called Int in your project?

Comment: You can't have a variable `currentYear As Date` and `currentYear As Integer` in the same scope. I presume you mean Integer not Int. You can't change the datatype of a variable with an As clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the current year, as an integer, like this:

```
Dim currentYear As Integer = Date.Now.Year
```

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

```
    Dim date1 As Date : Date.TryParse("11/02/2014", date1)
    Dim date2 As Date : Date.TryParse("02/12/2019", date2)

    Dim years As Integer =  CInt(DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, date1, date2))
    Dim days As Long = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, date1, date2)
    Dim hours As Long = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, date1, date2)

    Console.WriteLine("From start date has passed " &
          years.ToString & " years    OR " &
          days.ToString & "  days    OR " &
          hours.ToString & " hours ")
```

Comment: @G3nt_M3caj The preferred way of instantiating a date would be like `Dim date1 As Date = New DateTime(2014, 2, 11)`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help. I found some additional stuff online and was able to get it working with the following:

````
```
Dim startDate As Date
Dim startYear As Integer
startDate = #1/1/2014#
startYear = Year(startDate)

Dim currentDate As Date
Dim currentYear As Integer
currentDate = Today
currentYear = Year(Today)

Dim mfgYear As Integer
mfgYear = currentYear - startYear
```
````

I got my desired value of '5', and will get '6' when it reaches 2020 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Module Test
        Public Module DateAndTime
          Sub Main()
            Dim startYear As Int = 2014
            Dim currentYear As Date = DateTime.Now.Year
            mfgYear As Int = currentYear - startYear 
            ' result for mfgYear = 5
            Console.WriteLine(mfgYear)
          End Sub
        End Module
```

If you want just the current year you can use: `Dim DateNow As Integer = DateTime.Now.Year`