# How do i get the cropped integer number

Tags: c#

I'm trying to calculate the age based on the DOB.

```
Int32 DOB = 19900427;
Int32 current = 20140111;
Int32 result = current - dob;
```

Now i just need to display the starting 2 digit of the result in a text box. Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Please, read this thread [Date Difference in Years C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127363/date-difference-in-years-c-sharp). Yo find all you need there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do it that way. Just don't. You *can't* get a useful age representation by subtracting one value from another - you'll find that the difference between two people who were born a day apart can differ massively based on exactly when those dates are.

For example, consider three people with birth dates of:

```
A: December 30th 2013 - 20131230
B: December 31st 2013 - 20131231
C: January 1st 2014   - 20140101
```

That gives a difference between the ages of A and B of 1, but a difference between the ages of B and C of 8870. It's surely not good for you.

Use `DateTime` to represent dates - or preferably, use `LocalDate` from my [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) library. Then you can determine the difference between the dates however you want - potentially just in a number of days, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your speedy reply.

Comment: Here is my code :  DateTime date = DateTime.Today.Date;
        Int64 n = Int64.Parse(date.ToString("ddmmyyyy"));
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\adhar.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;");
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select dob from sample Where cardnum = '"+TextBox1.Text+"'");
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Int64 dob = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        Int64 result = n - dob;

Comment: @Partha: Why are you doing that at all? Just *don't* use this strange integer representation at all. You're not trying to represent an integer: you're trying to represent a date. SQL Server supports Date fields: use them. Also, use parameterized SQL rather than embedding values directly in the SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice sir. I finally succeeded in getting the calculating the correct age using datetime. Thanks once again!