# check if age is <18 datepicker wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm making an application where the user has to be more than 18. If he/she is less than 18 a `messageBox` appears saying "under age". I'm using a `datePicker`to select the users D.O.B. My problem is I'm not entirely sure on how to code this but I gave it a go by looking at tutorials but all the tutorials seem to be `dateTimePickers`.

My code is as follows:

xaml

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dpkDOB" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" />
```

xaml.cs

```
 int age = DateTime.Today.Year - tbkDOB.Value.Year;
 if (age < 18)
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Under age");
 }
```

Comment: What are the current results you're seeing? What's `tbkDOB` referring to?

Comment: Try adding the full year instead of 18 eg 1997

Comment: Did you mean `dpkDOB` instead of `tbkDOB`

Comment: yes I did mean `dpkDOB`

Comment: You also need to check day & month - if the birthday is later in the year then the person could be 17. Your best bet would be to subtract 18 years to todays date & compare the two dates. Check date & time functions here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_methods(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have tested in visual studio. Please find the below working code :

**XAML :**

```
<DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Center" Name="dpkDOB" Grid.Column="1" 
   VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" 
   SelectedDateChanged="dpkDOB_SelectedDateChanged"/>
```

**XAML.cs :**

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void dpkDOB_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ageInYears = GetDifferenceInYears(dpkDOB.SelectedDate.Value, DateTime.Today);
    if (ageInYears < 18)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Under age");
    }
}

int GetDifferenceInYears(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    return (endDate.Year - startDate.Year - 1) +
        (((endDate.Month > startDate.Month) ||
        ((endDate.Month == startDate.Month) && (endDate.Day >= startDate.Day))) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying `datePicker` does not contain definition for value.

Comment: The property you want to use is DisplayDate - check the documentation : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As stated in the original answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4127363/date-difference-in-years-c-sharp, this method is wrong. Luckily, a correct algorithm is given by dana just a little further down, although it has only 19 votes.

Comment: I have tried this but I get a runtime "Ivaled cast from Int32 to DateTime" using this code  DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);

   `DateTime a = Convert.ToDateTime( dpkDOB.SelectedDate.Value.Year);
            DateTime b = Convert.ToDateTime( DateTime.Today.Year);

            TimeSpan span = b - a;

            // because we start at year 1 for the Gregorian 
            // calendar, we must subtract a year here.
            int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1;
            if (years < 18)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Under age");
            }`

Comment: @CraigGallagher : Sorry for the delay. I was out of my desk for quite a long time. I have tested in visual studio and edited my answer and added the working code. Please try that.